# C++ Gain Sufficient Privilege to Bind to Port 80

Tags: c++, http, privileges

I am writing a C++ application that accepts HTTP request from browser and sending back the response.

```
int port = 2127; //80;
int bind_res = ::bind(port, p_ref->ai_addr, p_ref->ai_addrlen);
```

The application works as expected on OSX when I set it to listen at port 2127. But when I set it to listen on port 80, the application stopped working with exception:

> server: bind: Permission denied

My application is a command line application, and it opened by other GUI application, also written in C++ but with Qt.

How can I gain enough privilege to bind to port 80? Is there any API to show user and password prompt - like in XAMPP Control Panel, for example - to get those privilege?

EDIT:
I write the app for running on OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion.

Comment: OK, and I write the app for OSX.

Comment: If something else is already bound to port 80, then you'll get permission denied. Do you have a web server already listening on that port?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you cannot bind because of two issues:

1. something (Apache server, Skype) is already bound to that port.
2. you run as user and try to bind to a port below 1024.

It feels you have problem with that second case. For running with super user privileges there is `sudo` command on all Unixes (OSX is Unix).

If you do not like `sudo` then you can [permanently redirect the port to other port](https://serverfault.com/questions/183542/how-to-permanently-redirect-port-80-to-8080-on-os-x) that can be bound by user.

Comment: No, in case 1 you would get `EADDRINUSE`.

Comment: Yes Sir, I have problem with the second case and I able to bind to port 80 by using sudo. But instead of typing sudo, what i want is a pop-up dialog prompting username and password, because my app is not intended to run directly on terminal.

Comment: Yes but what about redirecting port 80 somewhere else? Thanks, Neil, corrected wording.